# Didn't rub my belly button during ghusl

Tags: fiqh, ghusl, fatwa, self-purification

Assalamualikum After doing GHUSL janabah I realised that I had not rubbed the inside of my belly button with my finger
So should I now assume that the water would have reached the inside of my belly button as I was using a shower or  do I have to redo my GHUSL
It's been 2-3 days since this and iam getting lot of doubts about the validity of my GHUSL

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. AFAIK rubbing the body parts is only a requirement in the Maliki school of jurisprudence.

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦️But I don't know wether the water reached the inside of my belly button should I assume it did. As I was using a shower